# iOS - Will the ViewController be deallocated after it's been removed from the parent controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on a app with register/login.

My root controller is a `UITabBarController`.

Every tab is a view controller individually.

I want to make one of them a login tab.

Every time the app is launched and the user switches to this tab, it checks whether the user is logged in. If not, it presents a **register controller** while it presents a **login controller** when the user is logged in.

To implement the function, I wrote two **view controllers** separately (the register one and the log in one).

To obey the **MVC** style, I also make two **UIView** class to render the view.

To summarize, the structure is

```
root viewcontroller(UITabBarController) -> user tab controller(UIViewController) -> login/register view controller(UIViewController -> login/register view(UIView)
```

`login/register controller` is a **childViewController** of `user tab controller`.

After the user has registered, I want the `register controller` to be removed from the `user tab controller`, which is its parent controller.

As I handle the touch event in the view(UIView), I make a **protocol** in it and make the user tab controller to be its **delegate**.

When the registration is completed, the view tell the delegate to remove its child controller.

```
#pragma mark - RegViewDelegate

-(void)parentViewControllerPop{
    [_cRegController removeFromParentViewController];
    NSLog(@"_cRegController removed from parent viewcontroller");
}
```

However, after that, the view is still showing on the screen, why?

I don't think what the design is a good one, but I don't know what is the best way to implement what I want.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why wouldn't it still be showing on the screen?  You haven't displayed anything else.

Comment: Why you are Using a TabBar Controller ? By using Navigation controller you can push and the pop the views controllers so that it wont be available in the view stack.

Comment: @Tibrogargan I think, as the view is the subview of the register controller, the view will be removed with the register controller. Once the register controller is not a child of the tab controller, it would disappear.

Comment: @Jinglei.Y It has nothing to do with removing it from the controller.  If you don't remove it from the view/window it will continue to be displayed until you replace it.  Once that happens it may be deallocated if there are no references to it elsewhere, but just removing it from the parent controller won't have much effect at all.

Comment: @Aneesh I use TabBar Controller is just because I want to put different kind of things in different sections. Just like there are 'home' tab and 'settings' tab. And I use a child controller in a tab is because I thought it makes the app more 'modular', although I don't know whether this is a good way or not (I haven't read much of others code so I don't know how developers **usually** do this).

Comment: @Tibrogargan Thanks. I thought that there was always 'one controller' displayed on the screen at a certain time. Can I think of the window as a 'box' and controllers just pile up inside it? Sorry if these questions are silly. I think I shouldn't put controllers inside another one, or if it is alright, how to switch among them? I've searched for many tutorials and they seem not to be very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

To remove a child view controller from his parent you need to do this 3 steps:

```
viewController.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)    
viewController.view.removeFromSuperview() 
viewController.removeFromParentViewController()
```

Reference: [Removing a Child View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html).